# Perform special action on bash timeout

Tags: linux, bash, exit, timeout, audit

This question is related only to `bash`, no `ssh` or any other tool.

I would like to detect a `bash` timeout, and only a timeout: I am **NOT** interested in any other exit conditions (`exit`, `EOF`, `^D`, or termination by any signal)

If you set the timeout variable:

```
$ TMOUT=10
```

When a timeout occurs, the following is displayed:

```
$ timed out waiting for input: auto-logout
```

This is put by `bash` itself, as seen in the implementation [here](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/d233b485e83c3a784b803fb894280773f16f2deb/eval.c#L245)

But appart from that console message, I have not found any way to detect that a timeout occured. I have tried the following code:

```
export TMOUT=10

function handle-termination {
    local retvalue=$1
    echo "retvalue=$retvalue"
    env > /tmp/env
    if [ "$retvalue" = "$(kill -l ALRM)" ] ; then
        echo "Timeout"
    else
        echo "Exit"
    fi
}

trap 'handle-termination $?' EXIT
```

Hoping that the return code `$?` from the timeout would provide an indication, but it is always `0`, no matter if a timeout or a manual exit triggered the `EXIT` signal.

Is there any way of reliably detecting detecting a `bash` session timeout?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a "timeout counter" into a function and if it finishes first, it'll kill the script, otherwise the function itself will be killed.

```
run_tout_counter() {
    sleep 10 & wait
    echo timeout
    rm /tmp/toutPID
    kill -s SIGINT $processPID
}
export processPID=$$
run_tout_counter &  echo $! > /tmp/toutPID

read -p "type input:" A &&  ps $(cat /tmp/toutPID)  >/dev/null

excode=$?
if [[ $excode == 0 ]] ; then kill -s SIGINT $(cat /tmp/toutPID)  ; fi && rm /tmp/toutPID
```